# Can we conclude $\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n)} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},b_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}})$

Tags: real-analysis

> Given any $\epsilon > 0$, can we conclude that $$\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (a_n,b_n)} \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left(a_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},b_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$

I don't know how to prove it in a rigorous way, or give a counter example. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, I think the answer is no. Pick $a_n=1/2^n$ and $b_n = 1-1/2^n$. Then the LHS is $\overline{(0,1)}=[0,1]$, but with $\epsilon=1/2$ the RHS is $(0,1)$, I think. Right?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: I think even $\epsilon=1$ will do, in fact.