# $P$ is collection of all finite open intervals, and define $m$ on $P$: $m((a,b)) = b-a$. About extending $m$ to a measure on $\mathscr{R}(P)$

Tags: real-analysis

> $P$ is collection of all finite open intervals, and define $m$ on $P$: $m((a,b)) = b-a$. Show that $m$ can be extended to a measure on $\mathscr{R}(P)$

Here $\mathscr{R}(P)$ is the ring generated by $P$. It's obvious that this is another way to define Lebesgue measure(I think it's more complicated than letting sets in $P$ have the form $(a,b]$). I am now struggling with proof that $m$ is countably additive on $\mathscr{R}(P)$. Below is my proof.

It can be shown that $\mathscr{R}(P) = \{A\bigcup B: \mbox{$A$ is union of finite open intervals and $B$ is a finite set}\}$. The $A$ mentioned can be decomposed into finite disjoint open intervals: $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{l}(a_i,b_i)$, and we can define $m(A) = \sum_{i=1}^l (b_i-a_i)$. Now for $E \in \mathscr{R}(P)$, suppose $E = A\bigcup B$, and we define $m(E) = m(A)$. It can be checked that $m(E)$ is independent of the form of decomposition, so the definition of $m$ on $\mathscr{R}(P)$ is reasonable.

Now we proceed to the proof that such $m$ is a measure on $\mathscr{R}(P)$. It's easy to prove that $m$ is nonnegative, finitely additive and monotonous. So it's left to show that $m$ is countably additive. Suppose $\{E_k\} \subset \mathscr{R}(P)$ are disjoint, $E_k = A_k \bigcup B_k$, and $E = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \in \mathscr{R}(P)$. By finite additivity and monotonicity we can show that 
$$
    m(E)\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k)
$$
On the other hand, we claim that $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $m(E) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k) + \epsilon$. Since $E \in \mathscr{R}(P)$, it has decomposition $E=A\bigcup B$, where $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^l (a_i,b_i)$. And for each $k$, $A_k$ is union of finite disjoint open intervals, so we have $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\alpha_n,\beta_n)$, where $\{(\alpha_n,\beta_n):n \geq 1\}$ are disjoint.

**Here** is what I am struggling with: I already have $A \bigcup B = (\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k) \bigcup (\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B_k)$. If we have 
$$
A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\alpha_n,\beta_n)
$$ 
then things will be much easier. But this may not be true, so what I am thinking is to prove that given $\epsilon > 0$, 
$$
A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\alpha_n - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}, \beta_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}})
$$
The reason why I am trying to prove this one is that if it holds, then we will have
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^l [a_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2l},b_i - \frac{\epsilon}{2l}]
\subset
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\alpha_n - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}, \beta_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}})
$$
By compactness, we have 
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^l [a_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2l},b_i - \frac{\epsilon}{2l}]
\subset
\bigcup_{j=1}^N (\alpha_{n_j} - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n_j+1}}, \beta_{n_j} + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n_j+1}})
$$
which implies
$$
\bigcup_{i=1}^l (a_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2l},b_i - \frac{\epsilon}{2l})
\subset
\bigcup_{j=1}^N (\alpha_{n_j} - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n_j+1}}, \beta_{n_j} + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n_j+1}})
$$
And then by monotonicity and finite additivity of $m$, we have
$$
m(E) -\epsilon = \sum_{i=1}^l (b_i - a_i - \frac{\epsilon}{l}) \leq \sum_{j=1}^N (\beta_{n_j} - \alpha_{n_j} + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n_j}}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\beta_n - \alpha_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2^n}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k) + \epsilon
$$
and we are done.

However, I just post a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/699762/can-we-conclude-overline-bigcup-n-1-infty-a-n-b-n-subset-bigcup-n-1/699784?noredirect=1#699784) and it seems 
$$
A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\alpha_n - \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}, \beta_n + \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}})
$$
might not be true. I am struggling here and any help will be appreciated.